# How to Display an Entry's Category?

Tags: templates, conditionals, categories

I'm on a single product entry page. The URL does not specify the category. In fact, the entry has 3 category groups associated with it. I want to display the first category assigned from each of the category groups.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1" }
<div id="prodinfo">
    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {exp:channel:categories category_group="4" note="vehicle type"}
    {category_name}
    {/exp:channel:categories}

</div> <!-- END #prodinfo -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is displaying all the categories in the group. I've also tried using the {if active} conditional variable, but as it relies on the URI, it's not working for me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're trying to use the wrong tag here.

That exp:channel:categories tag is for when you want to display a list of all the categories on your site - and possibly link to those "category listing" pages.

Here's how I display an individual entry's category:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="spc-content" limit="1" rdf="off" show_future_entries="no" status="open|Featured" require_entry="yes"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
{categories}<a href="{path=obsessive/compulsions}">{category_name}</a> {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

To change your code to display what you want, try this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1" }
<div id="prodinfo">
    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {categories}
    {category_name}
    {/categories}

</div> <!-- END #prodinfo -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: To expand you might want {categories limit="1"} to only show one tag - more: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories-tag-pair-parameters

Comment: Good point @llamcrean makes - if you want to display all the categories an entry is tagged with, my example works. If you only want to display one...use the limit parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Once @Leigh pointed me to the {categories} tag, I went and read the docs. Got everything happening the way I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: besides limit="1" any way to also restrict to a specific category group? category_group="1" doesn't seem to work for me when using the categories tag inside channel entries.

Comment: You want show_group= instead: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#show-group