# How to get entry's categories, of a specific Category Group

Tags: categories

I've followed [How to Display an Entry's Category?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7591/how-to-display-an-entrys-category) to show the categories assigned to a particular channel entry.

Is there a way to specify a certain Category Group?

For example, my code looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="training"}

    {categories}
        {category_name}<br>
    {/categories}

    {title}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So I have a channel called `training`. This contains a list of training courses, each of which is a channel entry. The above template lists the courses.

I then have **two separate** Category Groups assigned to my `training` channel. These are called *Training course category*  (ID == 1) and *Course type*  (ID == 2).

All I want to do in my `{categories} {/categories}` loop is work out whether the entry belongs to a specific *Course type*.

However, because each course has been assigned **multiple** categories (ID 1 and ID 2 Category Groups) it just outputs a list of any category that's been assigned. I understand this is expected behaviour. How can I alter the code so that it only looks for categories in Category Group 2?

ExpressionEngine version is 3.5.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which group the categories tag looks at.

```
{categories show_group="2"}
```

https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#show-group

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I couldn't find this in the EE 3 docs. https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/categories.html.

Comment: looks like they changed the parameter name.
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/categories.html#category-group

Comment: Apparently not. I tried that and it doesn't work. The code you gave (`show_group`) works, but is not documented (it is for EE 2, but not 3)! Weird.

Comment: submit a bug report

Comment: No change :) https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#show-group